# input string validation without external libraries for c++

Tags: c++, validation

I need to validate one input string from a user.  Eventually it will need to break down into two coordinates. ie a4 c3.  And once they are coordinates they need to be broken out into 4 separate ints.  a=0 b=1, etc.  They must also follow the following stipulations:

If an end-of-input signal is reached the program quits.
Otherwise, all non-alphanumeric characters are discarded from the input. 
If what remains is the single letter 'Q'
Then the program quits. 
If what remains consists of 4 characters, with one letter and one digit among the first two characters and one letter and one digit among the last two characters, and if each letter-digit pair is in the legal range for our grid
Then input is acceptable.

I have completely over-thought and ruined my function.  Please let me know where I can make some corrections.

I am mainly having trouble going from one string, to four chars if and only if the data is valid.  Everything else I can handle.

Here is what I have so far.

```
void Grid::playerMove()
{
    string rawMove;
    string pair1 = "  ";
    string pair2 = "  ";
    bool goodInput = false;
    char maxChar = 'a';
    char chary1, chary2;
    int x11,x22,y11,y22;
    for (int i =0; i<size; i++)
    {
        maxChar++;
    }

    while(!goodInput)
    {
        cout<<"What two dots would you like to connect? (Q to quit) ";
        cin>>rawMove;
        rawMove = reduceWords(rawMove);
        if (rawMove == "Q")
        {
            cout<<"end game";
            goodInput = false;
        }
        else if (rawMove.size() == 4)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            {
                if (pair1[j] >='a' && pair1[j] <=maxChar)
                {
                    chary1 = pair1[j];
                }
                else if(pair1[j] >=0 && pairl[j]<=size+1)
                {
                    x1 = pair1[j];
                }
            }
        for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
        {
            if (pair2[k] >='a' && pair2[k] <=maxChar)
            {
                chary2 = pair2[k];
            }
            else if(pair2[k] >=0 && pair2[k]<=size+1)
            {
                x2 = pair2[k];
            }
        }
    }
    if(char1 != NULL && char2 != NULL && x1 !=NULL && x2 != NULL)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m <= size m++)
        {
            if (char1 == m;)
            {
                x1 = m;
            }
        }
        for (int n = 0; n <= size n++)
        {
            if (char2 == n)
            {
                x2 = n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The end goal would be to have x1, x2, y1, and y2 with their respective values.

Keep in mind I am not allowed to have any external libraries.

Comment: I would suggest `<regex>`. It's part of the language standard.

Comment: Ok, normal pitfalls check, you are aware that `cin` stops on whitespace? What is `reduceWords`, how is it defined?

Comment: Does this even compile right now?  Char1, Char2, x1, & x2 are not defined anywhere (from what I can see).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what exactly you want to achieve, but here are some pointers to get you started:

1. The while loop will never end because you're setting `goodInput` to `false` on quit which lets the loop continue.
2. The code probably does not even compile?  You are missing a curly closing brace..
3. You are initializing `pair1` and `pair2` to empty strings but never change them again, so they will never contain any real information about your moves
4. *maybe* what you really want is to split up `rawMove` into the `pair1` and `pair2` substrings first?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework - and you're supposed to learn from those (right?) - I'm not going to give you the complete answer, but rather something like a recipe:

- Use `std::istream::getline(char*, std::streamsize s)` to read a whole line from `std::cin`. Make sure you allocate a buffer large enough to hold the expected input (including the terminating `null` character) plus some more for invalid characters. After the call, check the `failbit` (input was too long) and the `eofbit` (hit the end-of-input) of the `std::cin` stream and handle those cases. Construct a `std::string` from the buffer if there was no error or EOF has not been reached.
- Write a character-classification function (e.g. call it `isAlNum(char c)`) that returns `true` if the `char` argument is alpha-numeric, and `false` otherwise.
- Combine `std::string::erase()`, `std::remove_if()`, `std::not1()`, `std::ptr_fun()` and your function `isAlNum()` to sanitise the input string.
- Write a function that validates and parses the coordinates from the sanitised input string and call it with the sanitised input string.
- Wrap the whole thing in an appropriate `while()` loop.

This should get you started in the right direction. Of course, if you're allowed to use C++11 features and you know how to write good regular expressions, by all means, use the `<regex>` header instead of doing the parsing manually.